# C: Conversion from String to Double gives strange results

Tags: c, floating-point

I am tring to convert a string into a floating-point value. Take a look at my small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char string[3] = "42";
        double value = atof(string);
        printf("Floating-point value: %f\n", value);
        return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Floating-point value: 327680.000000
```

Why? The conversion from string to integer using `atoi` has worked very well!

If you have any idea why this is, please share your wisdom. :)

Comment: Your char needs to be big enough for a null terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char string[2] = "42";
```

should be

```
char string[3] = "42";
```

the size of `"42"` array is 3 bytes as you have to count the trailing null character. If you want use `char string[2]` for the declaration, your `string` will not be null terminated.

Then you also **have to** include `stdlib.h` file for `atof` declaration:

```
#incude <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Just edited that, thank you! It doesn't solve the issue, though, the output is still the same.

Comment: @baerenfaenger see my edit, you also have to include `stdlib.h` header. Next time be sure to enable all warnings in your compiler and fix all of them.

Comment: Why not just do `char string[] = "42";` and save yourself the trouble if you change the string constant.

Comment: @jucestain I used the `string[3]` to pinpoint the error, but indeed `string[]` is better here.

Comment: @ouah (Maybe SO glitch) On a re-freshed view of this I see OP's `#include <stdio.h> int main() {  char string[3] = "42"; ...` and _no_ indication it has been edited.  Did you see a different post?

Comment: @chux OP edited his question after my answer, during the first 5 minutes.